# eslint "parsing error: Unexpected token {" in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

```
const title = 'My Minimal React Webpack Babel Setups';

const App = () => (<div><b>{title}</b><img src={img} /></div>)
```

This code occurs an error **"ESLint Parsing Error: Unexpected token {"**

my **.eslintrc.js** file is like that

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb"
};
```

and I install the packages like that

```
"eslint": "^5.9.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
```

I thought that ESLint can read JSX because the token "<" doesn't occur error. (When I change the extends section in .eslintrc.js file to "airbnb-base", It occurs error "ESLint Parsing Error: Unexpected token <. But now, the token "<" doesn't occur error)

However, my ESLint cannot read the JSX syntax line {variable}

Comment: But there's no error in the code. It works right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yes. It works perfectly right. I can compile my code using babel, and It works clearly on my browser. But, ESLint say that **Parsing Error**.

Comment: Can you see if there are any ESLint upgrades?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman My ESLint version is latest version(5.9.0). I checking it using a command "npm update" and [npmjs.org site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Eslint on its own is not good enough. First install `babel-eslint`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

Or with yarn:

```
yarn add -D babel-eslint
```

Then add to your `.eslintrc` file:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

You might want to install `eslint-plugin-babel` as well, but I believe this is not needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All issues has been resolved. Should I install `babel-eslint`, when I doesn't use `babel` ?

Comment: You should. You don't need to use babel to install it. It just helps eslint with parsing the code @YouHoGeon

Comment: I just did that and it broke a ton of other stuff. This answer may be out of date...

Comment: @JamesBender don’t think so. Can you expand a little bit on your problem?

Comment: Potentially you may also need `"parser": "babel-eslint"` in your `.babelrc` along this this.

Answer (score 15):

I've got the same error on **Next.js**.

These steps solved my issue:

1) Install **babel-eslint**:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

2) Add **babel-eslint** as a **parser** to eslint config

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

---

My eslint config looks like this (**.eslintrc**):

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 9,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
    "no-console": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My .eslintr has this extra configuration to enable JSX

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It works same. Thanks you for comment.

Answer (score 3):

For all of those coming to this post as of March 2020 or later, there have been some updates to `babel` and `eslint` that result in the accepted answer being out of date.

Basically, if you're writing React and not using a framework like Next.js or create-react-app, and you're needing to configure `eslint` to work appropriately by hand, here is a quick guide to follow.

### Assumptions

This is assuming that you're starting a new project as of March 2020 and working with `eslint` 8.8 or later

### What to Install

Run the following

```sh
npm install @babel/eslint-parser @babel/preset-react
```

If you don't have `eslint-plugin-react` installed, you'll want to install that too in order to utilize the recommended `eslint` settings for React projects.

**Important**: If you have `babel-eslint` installed or present in your `package.json` still, `npm uninstall` it.

### How to Configure It

Example `.eslintrc.js` file (or `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json`)

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser', // <<<< Important
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false, // <<<< Allows you to skip Eslint complaining that you don't have a .babelrc file 
    babelOptions: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'], // <<<< Important
    },
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true, // <<<< Important
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {},
};
```

After following these updates, my project started working as expected.

### References

- https://tjaddison.com/blog/2021/03/updating-babel-eslint-to-babeleslint-parser-for-react-apps/